# Using Excel VBA to click through hover dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

How do we select dropdown option using VBA?

For example, my HTML source code looks like below, and I try to select second one, "코스피200 선물".

```
<select name="isu_cd" id="isu_cdc74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf">
    <option value="ALL">전체</option>
    <option value="KRDRVFUK2I">코스피200 선물</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Therefore, I try to iterate them using "For Each" after selecting that has name="isu_cd".

But the test for "MsgBox (botton.innnerHTML)" in the "For Each" gives me full of HTML code includes every other options as unexpected.

[image: Unexpected Results]

Could we iterate this with my approach?

```
Sub test_javascript()

    url = "http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/mdi#document=060101"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate url

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

    Set Buttons = ie.document.getElementsByName("isu_cd")

    For Each botton In Buttons

        MsgBox (botton.innerHTML) 'it gives all of HTML code unexpectedly

        If botton.innerHTML = "코스피200 선물" Then 'Nothing comes to here
            MsgBox (botton.innerHTML)
            botton.FireEvent ("onchange")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA? Using jquery makes it easier to achieve. `select the value which do not have "click" event` => you can use `onchange` event in the `<select>` element instead.

Comment: Thanks. I want to do this on your way. But I currently working with Excel VBA for specific demands of Company

Comment: Oh, I see. You embed the webpage into your VBA form. And your VBA form wants to detect what value is selected in the webpage. So you can use it for another purpose.

Comment: Have you tried `innerHTML`?

Comment: Yes. I got the same results. I also try " For Each botton In Buttons.Options" but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved!

Buttons(0).Value = "KRDRVFUK2I" changes the dropdown box into what I desired.

The full solution is in below.

```
Sub test_javascript()

    url = "http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/mdi#document=060101"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate url

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    Set Buttons = ie.document.getElementsByName("isu_cd")

    Buttons(0).Value = "KRDRVFUK2I"

    Set goandfind = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-board btn-board-search")(0)
    goandfind.Click

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    Set buttons_excel = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

    For Each botton In buttons_excel
        If botton.innerHTML = "Excel" Then

            MsgBox (botton.outerHTML)

            botton.FireEvent ("onclick")
            Exit For

        End If
    Next

    ' do whatever

End Sub
```

Comment: So, your point is to "set" the value, not "get" the value. I was missing here.

Comment: Yes. I change the dropdown item into the value that has "KRDRVFUK2I"